# Drawing a large number of ImageViews with the same Bitmap but different size

Tags: android

I am trying to draw multiple `ImageView`s inside a single `LinearLayout`.

All the `ImageView`s need to have a single bitmap. 
The ImageViews will only vary in size.
The single bitmap will not be resized.

The simple way is to create one Bitmap per ImageView. But, this runs out of memory quickly.

```
final Bitmap placeholderBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Config.ARGB_8888);
final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(placeholderBitmap);
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.placeholder_image), 0, 0, null);
imageView.setImageBitmap(placeholderBitmap);
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

I also tried setting the max and min height and width, no effect. The images remain the same size.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_no_image);
imageView.setMaxHeight(imageViewInfo.height);
imageView.setMaxWidth(imageViewInfo.width);
```

I believe working with `Drawable`s is the right "Android" way to do it, but I can't find a way to dynamically create a Drawable with the right side and layering the shared bitmap into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use one `Bitmap` -- as you say they will all use the same `Bitmap`, so no duplication is necessary.

If you want the `ImageView`s to have different sizes and have the `Bitmap` scale itself to the size of the `ImageView` then use the `setScaleType` or `android:scaleType` attribute to set the scaling of the `ImageView`. For instance `FIT_START` maintains the aspect ratio of your image and tries to fill the `ImageView` starting from the top-left corner.

I don't see any need to create a `Drawable`, though if you need to you can just create one from a `Bitmap` using:

```
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

`ImageView` actually does this automatically when you call `setImageBitmap(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

ImageView will always resize the bitmap to it need proportions.

If you want to save memory, resize the bitmaps manually and set them into the ImageViews this should stop the ImageView from resizing it internally - to make sure, you can set the layout_width and layout_hieght of the image view to 'wrap_content'.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. 
The Bitmap will not be resized.
Only the different ImageViews.
Edited.

Comment: still, the imageview will resize the bitmap internally - hence creating another copy of it. (possibly 2 - in the operation). If you need to save memory this is the correct approach. 100% sure.

Comment: The ImageView sets a scaling matrix into the canvas so *every* time it draws it uses to matrix to draw - which is a scaling operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think may be looking for a [ClipDrawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Clip).

You would set the `android:drawable` property of the clip XML to your bitmap

That or you can do it with the Java code also given in the example